# Function creates new user authentication in firebase but won't create a corresponding document in User collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a Function that creates a user document with corresponding userID in firestore when a user signs up.

```
function signup(email, password) {
  return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(cred => {
    return firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(cred.user.uid)
           .set({email})
    })
}
```

It creates a new user in authentication however it doesn't create the document in the user collection. I've used many variations of this code found on stackoverflow and various tutorials. Not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have already created the collection named `"users"`.

Edit your code as follows to log cred and/or errors so that you can effectively debug the issue.

```
function signup(email, password) {
  return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(cred => {
    console.log(cred);
    return firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(cred.user.uid)
           .set({email})
    })
}
// as you are returning promise from signup...
signup(email, password)
.then(() => console.log('doc written'))
.catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
```

Hopefully, this sets you in right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Both the operations return [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) so I'd recommend using an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

```
async function signup(email, password) {
  return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
    return firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({ 
      email
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("Document Added")
      return true
    })
  })
} 

// Handling the promise returned by signup function
signup(email, password).then(() => {
  console.log("User document added")
}).catch((e) => console.log(e))
```

Alternatively you can use the [`async-await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#the_basics_of_asyncawait) syntax like this.

```
async function signup(email, password) {
  try {
    const cred = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    await firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({
      email
    })
    return true
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    return e
  }
}
```